# Adobe Flex: How to periodically poll HTTP service?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I have an embedded system that serves JSON results via a CGI process.  I'm trying to setup a Flex app. to periodically poll the server once per second and update the GUI.  I'm trying the approach below using a timer, but I only get the initial result, subsequent updates are not made.  What could be going wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
               xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
               creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
        <mx:HTTPService id="getPacketCounts" showBusyCursor="true" resultFormat="text" 
                        url="http://10.1.10.28/cgi-bin/getpacketcounts" 
                        requestTimeout="500"
                        result="getPacketCounts_resultHandler(event)"
                        fault="faultHandler(event)">
        </mx:HTTPService>       
    </fx:Declarations>
    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
            import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;
            private var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 0);
            private var counter:int;

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerListener);
                timer.start();
            }

            private function timerListener(evt:Event):void {
                label.text = "get http://10.1.10.28/cgi-bin/getpacketcounts";
                getPacketCounts.send();
            }

            protected function getPacketCounts_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
            {
                label.text = event.result.toString().substr(0, 60);
            }           

            protected function faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
            {
                Alert.show("The server returned error code " + event.statusCode + ".", event.fault.faultString);
            }               
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>
    <s:Label id="label" text="v1.0"/>
</s:Application>
```

Comment: Could you post the code where you set up `timer`?

Comment: Sure, it's at http://resplendid.com/httptest.mxml.  SO not formatting my MXML correctly...

Comment: You should trace(event.result.toString().substr(0,60)) to make sure it's not getting the same result over and over.  Perhaps there's some sort of caching issue causing it to get the same value after the first request. Put in the trace and run in debug mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see anything glaringly wrong with your code though I suspect the problem lies with your `Timer` getting out of sync with your `HTTPService`. Your `Timer` fires every second but it might take longer for your `HTTPService` to return a result and the next tick of your `Timer` tramples over the previous `getPacketCounts.send()` request. I'm not 100% sure about this though.

If I were writing this app I'd set it up so the `Timer` fired once, reset the `Timer`, sent of the `HTTPService` request, then waiting for a response before restarting the `Timer`.

```
   // Make the Timer run once.
   private var timer:Timer = new Timer(1000, 1);

   // ....

   // Add listeners to the Timer and start it
   protected function application1_creationCompleteHAndler(event:FlexEvent):void
   {
       timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timerListener);
       timer.start();
   }

   // Send the request
   private function timerListener(e:TimerEvent):void
   {
       timer.reset();
       // Your other stuff
   }

   protected function getPacketCounts_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
   {
       timer.start()
       // Your code
   }           

   protected function faultHandler(event:FaultEvent):void
   {
       timer.start()
       // Your code
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion is a good one.  I've got the code now working fine on Firefox and Google Chrome, on IE9 Windows 7 I only see the initial load, it's as though the timer just fires once and the subsequent calls to timer.start() in the handlers do not do anything.  Any ideas on how to get it to work for IE?

Comment: @shaunhusain might be onto something with browser caching. Maybe try a simple cache busting technique like appending a timestamp to the request URL each time you send.